# Remover um valor de uma lista

Tags: python, spyder

Quero remover dois valores de uma lista. Do tipo tenho um vetor:

```
vet[0]*3

for i in range(3):
    vet[i]=input('Digite um valor: ')
```

Quero remover o máximo e o mínimo. Como faço?

Já tentei fazer `vet.remove(max(vet))`, mas não dá.

Answer (score 1):

Em python vc define uma lista assim:

```
vet = []
```

Para adicionar elementos na lista atraves de inputs vc pode fazer

```
for i in range(3):
   vet.append(int(input('Digite um valor: ')))
```

Digamos que o usuario tenha digitado 10, 20, 30, se voce quisesse ver o conteúdo de vet, poderia fazer:

```
print(vet)
```

E teria a saída:

```
[10, 20, 30]
```

Para excluir os elementos cujos valores sejam o máximo e o minimo:

```
# Excluindo o valor máximo:
vet.pop(vet.index(max(vet)))

# Excluindo o valor mínimo
vet.pop(vet.index(min(vet)))

# Imprimindo a lista resultante:
print(vet)
```

Saída:

```
[20]
```